# Using the Math.Pow function

Tags: c#, pow

I have a constructor that returns the result of two ints with a 'to the power of' operator. I am trying to use the math.pow method to do this but im not to sure how it work.

Here is my constructor

```
public int Power (int firstNumber, int secondNumber)
{
    result = Math.Pow(firstNumber, secondNumber);
    return result;
}
```

and the code that calls it

```
case "^":
    result = application.Power(firstInt, secondInt);
    labelResult.Text = ("" + result);
    break;
```

How do i use the Math.Pow method in this situation?

Comment: What don't you understand? Are you asking what variables are?

Comment: Sounds like he doesn't understand what "constructor" means.  Or the difference between instance and static methods.  Or how to convert a double to int.  Or a number to a string.  Hard to guess, too many things wrong.

Comment: I am trying to figure out how to do the power of two ints as the result = Math.Pow(firstNumber, secondNumber); returns error: Error 1 Cannot implicitly convert type 'double' to 'int'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?) S:\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Calculator\Calculator\Calculations.cs 39 22 Calculator

Comment: "Are you missing a cast?"  (int)true.

Comment: Give a bit more info on what you are struggling with if you would. The [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.pow(v=vs.110).aspx) page should tell you everything you need to know. [Dotnetperls](http://www.dotnetperls.com/math-pow) also gives an explanation with examples.

Comment: That isn't a constructor.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As far as the error you're getting:

Math.Pow takes 2 doubles as arguments and returns a double. Your method is declared as returning an int. This means that **result** is an int. You need to cast the result of Math.Pow to int:

```
result = (int)Math.Pow(firstNumber, secondNumber);
```

Answer (score 6):

Basically, it returns a specified number raised to the specified power.

The first argument contains the value you want to use

The second argument contains the power value you want to implement.

For example, if you have this

```
result = Math.Pow(3, 3);
return result;
```

It will return value **27** because it is 3 x 3 x 3.

But if I write

```
result = Math.Pow(1, 3);
return result;
```

It will return value of **1** because it is 1 x 1 x 1.

What if I write the 1st argument of 5 and 2nd argument 1?

```
result = Math.Pow(5, 1);
return result
```

It will return as **5** because it is 5 x 1.

You can figure it your own.
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_pow

**UPDATED**

Here's the example of the input. Use **Power** instead of declaring **application.Power**

```
case "^":
    result = Power(firstInt, secondInt);
    labelResult.Text = ("" + result);
    break;
```

Comment: Thankyou, what I am trying to ask is how can i use firstInt and secondInt as the paramaters for Math.Pow instead of hard numbers

Comment: @ultrapulse May I know what is the input code? Is it user writing text inside the textbox?

Comment: the input code are ints passed to Math.Pow by the user with the variable name firstInt and secondInt

Comment: @ultrapulse Read my updated post

Answer (score 2):

Like Minelava said, the Math.Pow method has two parameters, the first parameter indicates the number you are trying to base the result on. The second parameter is the exponent itself.

```
Math.Pow(3, 2) = 3 * 3 = 9

Math.Pow(2, 3) = 2 * 2 * 2 = 8
```

If you like, you could directly call the Math.Pow method, so you do not need Power method anymore. I think it's more simple otherwise you have another concern to have other Power method.

```
case "^":
    result = Math.Pow(firstInt, secondInt);
    labelResult.Text = ("" + result);
    break;
```

Just my two cents.
Thanks.